# React native flatlist footer

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I am new to react native. How can I  pass some data to flat list's footer component? I tried extraData property of flat list but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this:

- you can make your footer component a sub-component of your other component and use the state of the parent component to modify the footer as well (most easy)
- you can use a global state like with Context, Redux, Recoil, etc.